# Messaging - All attributes or just an id pointer

Tags: rest, msmq, messaging, nservicebus, amqp

We are considering integrating messaging (publishing events) in our system, we multiple components, a few different stacks etc.. We'll start with a small number of publishers and subscribers and gradually introduce where it makes sense.

If we publish an event, say type: 'NewProductAddedToCatalogue', should it included all the attributes of the new product or just the new product Id or some form of rest url perhaps e.g. http://db.intranet/products/[uuid]. What are the advantages of each approach? I feel some subscribers would just be interested in a minimal number of attributes whilst others e.g. website publisher might want access to them all (or most). Are there any significant downside to either approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick answer - why not publish two types of event message?

One could be a lightweight event with just the product ID and this would be used by subscribers who would then enrich the event data themselves.

The other message would contain all the data needed to make sense of the event, for consumers who didn't want to enrich the data.

The longer answer - I don't really like the "lightweight" event idea. The problem with this is that you are basically turning your event message into a "something changed" notification.

This removes the event from it's underlying data change - for example a notification does not say what has changed, but only that something has changed. It's entirely possible that the event message may have been delayed to the point where the underlying data is no longer in the same state as it was when the event was raised (whether this is a problem for you is down to your individual requirement).

**More importantly** however, the lookup to "enrich" the data introduces coupling between components - the idea behind an event message is that the event subscriber can just process it - the subscriber doesn't need to know anything about the publisher of the message - or, more specifically, about the data source that the message came from.

However, there are some benefits - notification-type message processing is [idempotent](http://www.soapatterns.org/idempotent_capability.php) by nature so there's less effort involved there.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting topic we've discussed at length since our product catalog is at our core.  What we've found is that each Subscriber will be interested in a common set of data and then it will enhance that data with its own.  An example of that would be a Marketing subscriber that would add consumer friendly images and descriptions. This is quite different than a Supply Chain subscriber that would add things like height, weight, and cube.  This approach works when each component is responsible for its own data.

If you are in the situation where your some of catalog is centrally managed, we've found that its easiest to send each Subscriber the common elements plus the data that it is interested in.  We've found that there really isn't a ton of overlap in the data and you can keep your systems decoupled.